# Python not finding appropriate modules/ python version problems

Tags: macos, python, macports

I'm trying to install w3af, and getting a myriad of dependency issues; these I'm trying to resolve by attempting to run a python script which imports the required modules - if this runs without issues, so should w3af, or at least, that's my theory.

I have installed all of the dependencies with MacPorts, and I can see them all in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-package
```

Yet whenever I run my test script which imports the dependencies, say, "pybloomfilter", I simply get;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pybloomfilter
ImportError: No module named pybloomfilter
```

Despite the module clearly residing in the aforementioned directory. I suspect I am using the wrong python version somehow; I have tried calling python2.7, but get the same result, I have also tried rerunning macports command to change the python version to the "right" one. Cheers for any help.